# Container lookup not finding the wrong class

Tags: ember.js

I have 2 authenticators registered in my application:

```
    container.register('app:authenticators:backend',  GambifyApp.BackendAuthenticator);
    container.register('app:authenticators:facebook',  GambifyApp.FacebookBackendAuthenticator);
```

The issue is now, I have some GambifyApp.FacebookBackendAuthenticator, which is then getting problematic.

When debugging I see that _this.container.lookup('app:authenticators:backend') has following parameters:

```
__proto__:
     _debugContainerKey: "app:authenticators"
     constructor: GambifyApp.FacebookBackendAuthenticator
```

How can I get the only GambifyApp.BackendAuthenticator when calling container.lookup('app:authenticators:backend')?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Now that I see what you're saying, I see the issue. You're using 2 colons in the registry name. The container doesn't really like that. But to me, it seems like the `app` prefix is a little unnecessary. Try using just `authenticators:backend` and `authenticators:facebook`. If the `app` prefix really is necessary, use `app:backendAuthenticator` and `app:facebookAuthenticator`.

Comment: I don't necessarily need a new instance, I just want the correct instance. Its ok If there is exactly one instance of my BackendAuthenticator and my FacebookBackendAuthenticator. I just want the correct one returned by lookup, which is currently not the case.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer to reflect that.